# Border does not show on Button

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, button, mouseevent

I am new to `WPF` and is maybe to simple. I can not figure out why `BorderBrush` does not show on the remove `Button`. The `Button` is by default not visible but show when the mouse is over the `Button`. When the mouse is over the `Button` the underlying `TextBlock` show as it should, but without `Border`.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I view the button's `Border`.

Following is my `XAML`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="325">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MakeToolbarVisible">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.5"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MakeToobarHidden">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Style x:Key="Toolbar">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MakeToobarHidden}"/>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MakeToolbarVisible}"/>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Border>
        <Grid Margin="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="enter some text here!" Margin="8,19.058,8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#B43C1C26" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <TextBox TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="8,19.058,0,2.463" FontSize="11" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" Visibility="Visible" BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}"/>
            <WrapPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="8,8,8,8">
                <TextBlock Text="29.8.1995" Foreground="#B43C1C26" FontSize="10" />
            </WrapPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,5,8" Grid.RowSpan="2" Opacity="0" Style="{StaticResource Toolbar}">
                <Button x:Name="Remove" BorderBrush="DarkRed" BorderThickness="1" Cursor="Hand">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="r" FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="12"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace the Buttons default template with a template which has no border, by setting the Buttons ControlTemplate.

To display a Border, add it in your ControlTemplate like so:

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,5,8" Grid.RowSpan="2" Opacity="0" Style="{StaticResource Toolbar}">
            <Button x:Name="Remove" BorderBrush="DarkRed" BorderThickness="1" Cursor="Hand">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                             <TextBlock Text="r" FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="12"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

Via TemplateBinding you can bind to Properties of the templated control, in this case the Button's Properties.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new. Your solution works as I expected

Answer (score 0):

You have overriden the `ControlTemplate` of your `Button` so you would loose the default template of button.

As per your code, what i can see is you want to set the `FontFamily` and `FontSize` for text in your button which you can achieve without overriding the template like this -

```
       <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,5,8" Grid.RowSpan="2" Opacity="0"
                   Style="{StaticResource Toolbar}">
            <Button x:Name="Remove" BorderBrush="DarkRed"
                    BorderThickness="1" Cursor="Hand" Content="r"
                    FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="12"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button to look like a regular button, you should not retamplte it
just set the properties you want to change like so :

```
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,5,8" Grid.RowSpan="2" Opacity="0" Style="{StaticResource Toolbar}">
     <Button x:Name="Remove" BorderBrush="DarkRed" BorderThickness="1" Cursor="Hand"
                            FontSize="12" FontFamily="Marlett" Content="r"/>

   </StackPanel>
```